Conic section illustration
I'm currently studying
Introduction to Tensor Calculus and Continuum Mechanics
and on page 151 I'm puzzled by the right-hand illustration of a conic section. Here's the definition of a conic section using the focal point $F$ and directrix $D$, s.t. $\frac{\overline{FP}}{\overline{PD}} = $, with  $ < 1$ for an ellipse.
The question is, how can
$$\overline{FP_{1}} \ =\ q$$
and
$$\ \overline{P_{1} D} =\ q$$
Here is an illustration

It's not clear what your question is. The point $P_1$ is vertex of the ellipse at periapsis $q$ (minimum distance from the focus $F$). It is on the major axis and is the midpoint of the segment connecting the nearer focus $F$ and the perpendicular directrix line.

@SammyBlack What I meant was that if $\overline{FP_{1}} \ =\ q$ and $\overline{P_{1} D} =\ q$, then $\frac{\overline{FP_{1}}}{\overline{P_{1} D}} \ =\ 1$ , but this ratio defines parabola, not the ellipse

Oh, yeah, you're totally right. If it's the midpoint, then that ratio is $1$, hence a parabola. The diagram is mislabeled. The segment $\overline{FP}_1$ should be labeled $\varepsilon q$.
